# php a for loop machine

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a array which stored few integers
I expect to use table and the for loop loop through the array
therefore, the details of the code probably like as below:

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++){
<table>
<tr><td>$array[$i]</td></tr>
</table>
```

However, I would like to add a function:
each of the table row is specified to 2 columns,

finally the result should like as following.

34 23

11 10

29 10
......and so on.

plz help me ,thanks a lot :)

Comment: Where are you stuck? Write the table you want first in HTML only. Where it works, write the PHP code to create it dynamically.

Comment: Don't delete the text of your question when your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
<?php
$size = sizeof($array);              // Store the size to reduce computations
for($i=0;$i<$size;$i+=2)              // Loop through the array
{
    echo("<tr>");                    // Print row begin tag
    echo("<td>".$array[$i]."</td>"); // Print out first column value
    if ($i + 1 < $size)              // If we can, print out the second column value
        echo("<td>".$array[$i+1]."</td>");
    echo("</tr>");                   // Print row end tag
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: this is wrong. correct it please.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? It prints out what @Rom Chan wants...

Comment: ok but please. check it with this. $array=(1,2,3,4,5,6);. I think it will out put something like this. (1|2)(2|3)(3|4)(4|5)(5|6). instead of (1|2)(3|4)(5|6). so its wrong. don't you agree with me?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
<?php
function printRows($arr) {
    print '<tr>';
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        print '<td>' . $arr[$i] . '</td>';
        if($i%2!=0&&$i!=count($arr)-1) print '</tr><tr>';
    }
    print '</tr>';
}
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
?>
```

Usage:

```
<table>
    <?php printRows($arr); ?>
</table>
```

Comment: hi.why you suggest this? why is mine's problem?(:. and I think also yours is wrong(:

Comment: I might have misunderstood "add a function", but I think it will be easier to understand. Just an alternative suggestion :)

Comment: ok but I think yours is wrong.

Comment: You're right, fixed now. Leading empty row was a bug, but I've now tested it.

Comment: ok its now working.but is not mine good enough.could not you just vote me up? its ok no need to vote me up but this is called.good supporting. anyway have a good day.(: